# Valgrind cannot attach on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, gdb, valgrind

When I run valgrind with the options `--tool=memcheck --db-attach=yes` and then try to attach when an error pops up i get: `valgrind: m_debugger.c:235 (ptrace_setregs): Assertion 'Unimplemented functionality' failed.` It seems odd to me that this would not be implemented as it is such a core feature to valgrind. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to Valgrind 3.7.0 and use the embedded gdbserver.
See Valgrind 3.7.0 user manual for more details